# Live stream audio from multiple devices simultaneously

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, live-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

This is what I want to achieve.

1.There is a channel. And only selected users can live stream audio to the channel while everyone can listen.

- Those selected users can be streaming audio from different devices.

Is it possible to do something like this using streaming engines like wowza etc. If not any directions on how to proceed.

This might look similar to a conference call where some users are muted.

I am looking for a scalable solution.

Comment: You'll have to explain more in detail what you want.  "some" users are muted... like almost all of them?  What sorts of scale for both the source end and the listeners?  "scalable solution" doesn't give us enough information, as solutions need to be much more targeted when you grow.  Is there ever more than one person that is the source?  If there are multiple, what happens to their audio?  Is it mixed together?  What platforms are you targeting, for both the source end and the listeners?  The users streaming... do they swap in and out with others regularly?  More details are needed.

Comment: have you looked at WebRTC